# Render transparent object distortions but not the transparent object

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render some artifical object behind glass.

This object has its material properties in such a way that it produces refraction (raytrace transparency with IOR > 1), reflections, and it casts a shadow.

The setup:

[image]

I use a real-life image as a background to render the scene, you can see the results before and after the process:
[image]
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30pFzvcwQnc

Please note that the model is not an accurate representation of the real object (I'm ok with that).

I want to get rid of the transparent model on the right image and **keep only the distortions** on the apples, the reflections of the apples on the object and the shadow cast upon the table (there is no real table in the model, it's just the image)

It should look like the original object (the glass on the left image) is casting the shadow and producing the refraction and the reflections.

As the model is an approximation of the real thing, it is ok not to have accurate distortions.

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: No, I´m quite new in blender

Comment: Gandalf is asking which renderer you are using. Blender Internal or cycles? Check the drop down in the header at the top.

Comment: Ups, it is Blender Internal

Comment: You can separate the reflections/refractions by enabling those passes in *Properties > Renderlayers*.